# Cannot read a key from S3 with boto, but can with aws cli

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, aws-cli

Using this aws cli command (with access keys configured), I'm able to copy a key from S3 locally:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<bucketname>/test.txt test.txt
```

Using the following code in boto, I get S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden, whether I allow boto to use configured credentials, or explicitly pass it keys.

```
import boto
c = boto.connect_s3()
b = c.get_bucket('<bucketname>')
k = b.get_key('test.txt')
d = k.get_contents_as_string() # exception thrown here
```

I've seen the other SO posts about not validating the key with validate=False etc, but none of these are my issue. I get similar results when copying the key to another location in the same bucket. Succeeds with the cli, but not with boto.

I've looked at the boto source to see if it's doing anything that requires extra permissions, but nothing stands out to me.

Does anyone have any suggestions? How does boto resolve its credentials?

Comment: Sometimes it is because boto might be making a different API call to `aws s3 cp`. This is because there isn't a 1-to-1 mapping between `get_contents_as_string()` and an API call like `s3:GetObject`. What permissions are associated with the User/Role? Can you temporarily add all S3 permissions to see if that fixes it?

Comment: yeah, i'm thinking boto is requiring more permissions than the cli, though i can't see what from the source

Comment: @SimonTrewhella I am encountering a similar problem, did you find any solution to this? Which other permissions are required specifically, or a workaround?

Comment: @monguin I ended up having to add access keys in the code, and i think switch to boto2

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set your credentials so that our the same as the CLI with the ENV variables.

*echo $ACCESS_KEY*

*echo $SECRET_KEY*

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
 )

b = client.get_bucket('<bucketname>')
k = b.get_key('test.txt')
d = k.get_contents_as_string()
```

How boto resolves its credential.

> The mechanism in which boto3 looks for credentials is to search through a list of possible locations and stop as soon as it finds credentials. The order in which Boto3 searches for credentials is:
>
> - Passing credentials as parameters in the boto.client() method
> - Passing credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
> - Environment variables
> - Shared credential file (~/.aws/credentials)
> - AWS config file (~/.aws/config)
> - Assume Role provider
> - Boto2 config file (/etc/boto.cfg and ~/.boto)
> - Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#guide-configuration